# Sergeant Sequence dodges a bullet

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, story

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #49: Pub Quiz Camouflage](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7159/)</sup>

---

After a long day at the office with little to show for it, an evening at The Badger and Biscuit (his favourite pub) was exactly what Sergeant Sequence needed to unwind. Plus, Monday night was 'KWIZ NITE' (as the owners insisted on spelling it), which was always good fun, if a little pop-culture-heavy at times.

Sequence had known the barman (known to all as 'Lando') for many years - and certainly well enough to realise from Lando's cagey, almost distant greeting on his arrival at the bar that something was wrong. With a silent nod, Sequence returned to his quiz team at their table in the corner of the pub, drinks in hand, and waited for the signal...

Lando and Sergeant Sequence had established their emergency protocol many years earlier, and only ever had to use it two or three times. On one occasion the secret code had entirely passed the sergeant by (and an opportunity to arrest his nemesis - Patrick Terne - along with it), but tonight he was alert and ready for it. The last 20 questions of the evening's quiz - that was always where the coded message lurked. And sure enough, come the end of the quiz, Sequence gazed down at the answers on his paper and spotted Lando's concealed warning.

(Thanks to Lando's tip-off, Sergeant Sequence returned to the station after work and mobilised his team. Within the hour, a known associate of Patrick Terne was taken into custody, arrested before a planned assassination attempt on the sergeant's life could be made.)

> **TASK: Answer the last 20 questions of the evening's quiz and find Lando's concealed message for Sergeant Sequence. (Please try to complete as much of the puzzle as possible before posting an answer - no partial answers solving just a handful of the trivia questions, thank you!)**

> ...
> 31.   As a result of its shape, which variety of pasta is named after the Italian word for ‘butterfly’?
> 32.   Which animal cell organelles break down macromolecules, repair cell membranes, and destroy invading viruses and bacteria?
> 33.   Which form of headgear, designed to expose only part of the face, is named after a town near Sevastopol, in the Crimea?
> 34.   Which field of mathematics completes the popular phrase: “Lies, damned lies, and ___”?
> 35.   Belgrade is the capital city of which European country?
> 36.   Which US tennis player has won the most Grand Slam singles titles of any player in the Open Era – 23, to date?
> 37.   Which English pop duo recorded the festive hit *Last Christmas* in 1984?
> 38.   Which British actress is known for roles in *Mulholland Drive*, *The Ring*, and *King Kong*?
> 39.   Cyclops, Storm and Wolverine are characters in which Marvel Comics franchise?
> 40.   Which US President took office in 2000 despite ‘losing the popular vote’ to his rival, Al Gore?
> 41.   Which graphic novel by Alan Moore and David Lloyd was adapted for the big screen in 2005 by the Wachowski siblings?
> 42.   Which song – originally written by Prince – became a worldwide chart hit for Sinéad O’Connor in 1990?
> 43.   DC Comics’ “Kal-El” is more widely known by which 8-letter alter-ego?
> 44.   Which Beatles song is the opening track on their 1966 album, *Revolver*?
> 45.   Which aquatic insect in the order *Ephemeroptera* is often considered a byword for something shortlived, as many species live for just long enough to reproduce, before dying?
> 46.   What name is given to the closely-mowed section of a golf course between the tee and the green?
> 47.   English rock band Coldplay performed one of their biggest hits *twice* during the closing ceremony of the 2012 Paralympic Games – which one?
> 48.   Which word completes the title of the 1955 William Holden film, ***BLANK** Is a Many-Splendored Thing*?
> 49.   Which letter of the alphabet represents both one of the 4 human blood types and one of the 4 DNA bases?
> 50.   Which song was a UK Number One hit for Welsh singer Duffy in 2008?

Comment: Just a note to solvers: 'Lando' is purely an affectionate shortening of 'Landlord' - no clues to solving the puzzle hidden within the name :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The sergeant was told

> **DONT GO HOME**!

---

Answers to the questions:

> ...
>  31.  As a result of its shape, which variety of pasta is named after the Italian word for ‘butterfly’?  **FARFALLE**
>  32.  Which animal cell organelles break down macromolecules, repair cell membranes, and destroy invading viruses and bacteria?  **LYSOSOME**
>  33.  Which form of headgear, designed to expose only part of the face, is named after a town near Sevastopol, in the Crimea?  **BALACLAVA**
>  34.  Which field of mathematics completes the popular phrase: “Lies, damned lies, and ___ ”?  **STATISTICS**
>  35.  Belgrade is the capital city of which European country?  **SERBIA**
>  36.  Which US tennis player has won the most Grand Slam singles titles of any player in the Open Era – 23, to date?  **SERENA WILLIAMS**
>  37.  Which English pop duo recorded the festive hit *Last Christmas* in 1984?  **WHAM!**
>  38.  Which British actress is known for roles in *Mulholland Drive*, *The Ring*, and *King Kong*?  **NAOMI WATTS**
>  39.  Cyclops, Storm and Wolverine are characters in which Marvel Comics franchise?  **X-MEN**
>  40.  Which US President took office in 2000 despite ‘losing the popular vote’ to his rival, Al Gore?  **GEORGE W. BUSH**
>  41.  Which graphic novel by Alan Moore and David Lloyd was adapted for the big screen in 2005 by the Wachowski siblings?  **V FOR VENDETTA**
>  42.  Which song – originally written by Prince – became a worldwide chart hit for Sinéad O’Connor in 1990?  **NOTHING COMPARES 2 U**
>  43.  DC Comics’ “Kal-El” is more widely known by which 8-letter alter-ego?  **SUPERMAN**
>  44.  Which Beatles song is the opening track on their 1966 album, *Revolver*?  **TAXMAN**
>  45.  Which aquatic insect in the order *Ephemeroptera* is often considered a byword for something shortlived, as many species live for just long enough to reproduce, before dying?  **MAYFLY**
>  46.  What name is given to the closely-mowed section of a golf course between the tee and the green?  **FAIRWAY**
>  47.  English rock band Coldplay performed one of their biggest hits *twice* during the closing ceremony of the 2012 Paralympic Games – which one?  **PARADISE**
>  48.  Which word completes the title of the 1955 William Holden film, ***BLANK** Is a Many-Splendored Thing*?  **LOVE**
>  49.  Which letter of the alphabet represents both one of the 4 human blood types and one of the 4 DNA bases?  **A**
>  50.  Which song was a UK Number One hit for Welsh singer Duffy in 2008?  **MERCY**

A list of the answers:

> **FARFALLE**
> **LYSOSOME**
> **BALACLAVA**
> **STATISTICS**
> **SERBIA**
> **SERENA WILLIAMS**
> **WHAM!**
> **NAOMI WATTS**
> **X-MEN**
> **GEORGE W. BUSH**
> **V FOR VENDETTA**
> **NOTHING COMPARES 2 U**
> **SUPERMAN**
> **TAXMAN**
> **MAYFLY**
> **FAIRWAY**
> **PARADISE**
> **LOVE**
> **A**
> **MERCY**

There is a clue in the questions here

> Look at the first letters of the questions. They go in a pattern of 'AWWW', 'BWWW', 'CWWW' etc. This is clueing that the questions can be split into groups of 4.
>
> So as Jeremy Dover and oAlt realised, and as the sergeant's name suggests, each of these groups will act as a sequence. We need to find the next item in each sequence, and putting them together will give the answer.

So, sorting the words:

> GROUP 1:
>
> **FARFALLE**, **LYSOSOME**, **BALACLAVA**, **STATISTICS**
>
> All of these contain a musical note, repeated: 'FA', 'SO', 'LA', 'TI'. The remaining note is therefore '**DO**'

> GROUP 2:
>
> **SERBIA**, **SERENA WILLIAMS**, **WHAM!**, **NAOMI WATTS**
>
> (Solved by Mohirl) If you look at the first letters we get 'S', 'SW', 'W' and 'NW'. These are compass directions, and the next would be '**N**'

> GROUP 3:
>
> **X-MEN**, **GEORGE W. BUSH**, **V FOR VENDETTA**, **NOTHING COMPARES 2 U**
>
> Each involve one of the last letters of the alphabet, in reverse order: 'X', 'W', 'V' and 'U'. The next letter would be '**T**'

> GROUP 4:
>
> **SUPERMAN**, **TAXMAN**, **MAYFLY**, **FAIRWAY**
>
> If we take the first parts of these compound words, we get 'SUPER TAX' and 'MAY FAIR'. These are two locations on a monopoly board, and the next would be '**GO**'

> GROUP 5:
>
> **PARADISE**, **LOVE**, **A**, **MERCY**
>
> 'Paradise, Love, A Mercy' are all books by Toni Morrison. [If we look at the next book in publication order](https://www.bookseriesinorder.com/toni-morrison/) we see the next one is called '**HOME**'

So the message is:

> **DONT GO HOME**!

Comment: To confirm, all 20 answers are correct, although one of them can be *written slightly differently*, which might help you spot what's going on here... Ignore 'ASCII' - that's a delicious but entirely unintentional red herring! :)

Comment: @Stiv hmmm interesting, I can see 3 or 4 that I could write slightly differently so I’ll have to think about that. Typical of me to somehow find a red herring like that :P

Comment: Let's just say that as things stand one of your answers is ambiguous - there is another (pretty much standard) way to write it that differentiates it from another 'of its kind'... Spot that and you've got an 'in'...

Comment: Pretty sure the ambiguity Stiv is referring to is #41: rot13(Guvf Trbetr Ohfu jnf bsgra ersreerq gb nf J, uvf zvqqyr vavgvny. Guvf tvirf gur frevrf bs nafjref K,J,I,H, gubhtu V'z abg fher jung gb qb jvgu vg. Nyfb, gur svefg sbhe nafjref unir n abgr (sn, fb yn, gv) ercrngrq.)

Comment: @JeremyDover I assume you meant 40, and I was debating whether or not to write it like that or how I've written it in the answer while writing it. Also interesting observations! I have a feeling it'll be a multi-gimmick, the words will split into groups with their own puzzle and solution, not sure where to start though

Comment: Yep, that was indeed the one :) And @JeremyDover is definitely onto something... I'll leave you to it...!

Comment: (edited due to typo) ROT13: Vg srryf yvxr gurfr ner frevrf bs guvatf (urapr Frdhrapr'f anzr bapr ntnva), juvpu arrq gb or svavfurq. Gurersber, nsgre "gv" vf "qb", naq nsgre 'h' vf 'g' (abgvat gur erirefr beqre bs gur frevrf), juvpu znl or tvivat hf "QB [fbzr yrggref] G [fbzr zber yrggref]" sbe gur svany zrffntr. V unir nofbyhgryl ab pyhr nobhg jung gur bgure guerr frevrf ner, gubhtu...

Comment: @oAlt oooh good thinking. I tried using sequence as in a fibonacci sequence of something and take the xth letters but that dfeinitely seems to be the right things here. It would seem there are 5 groups of 4, and that seems right when you split it up - the words look somewhat similar in style. I'm going to edit that in to at the very least help some other people

Comment: Now you're getting somewhere :) You're *very* close with Group 5 - but the book you've linked to isn't a *single* book... (Read the Amazon listing more closely...)

Comment: Group two is rot13(qverpgvbaf - F, FJ, J, AJ, fb gur arkg jbhyq or A znxvat gur svefg jbeq QBA'G)

Comment: For group 5: as per the hint, it's rot13(N ahzore bs obbxf ol gur nhgube, gur arkg bs juvpu jnf Ubzr.). It then seems like the answer to group 4 should be rot13(TB), though I'm not seeing how

Comment: @Mohirl good spot! Just group 4 to go now. And don't worry, I found group 5

Comment: @Stiv solved it all now, except linking the last 2 words in group 4, but with a bit of digging I should be able to find it. Very nice puzzle!

Comment: Very close to the end! Not quite the right word for Group 4 yet (once you spot what the words have in common you'll realise what you're missing...). Funny, I didn't think of this as a rot13(Pbaarpg Jnyy) at all when creating it (since no rearrangement is required) - instead there is another mechanism within the questions themselves that was there to help you spot this... Can you see it? :)

Comment: @Stiv spotted the clue in the questions, and drat I was convinced I had the right word considering that superman reference :P

Comment: Okay, this is now complete! Thanks for solving :) Checkmark landing in 5... 4... 3...

Comment: Sergeant Sequence is a brilliant analyst and has excellent broad knowledge. But he is also specifically British, because one of the answers (4) would be unknown to, for example, a North American puzzler. Those have different names in the original, familiar NA version of the object.

Comment: 4 is definitely very location specific

Comment: @Sinc Indeed he is (and indeed they do)! But the London version is the standard throughout the Commonwealth, so I'd say it's still sufficiently widely known that many non-Brits might spot the connection - particularly in a puzzling community, where pursuits like puzzles, quizzes and board games often go hand in hand... :)

Comment: @Sinc also, if you search the terms into google you’ll instantly be met with the board, so could be found that way!

Comment: Based on comments here and in chat, I think Stiv wants you to indicate that rot13(rnpu tebhc vf n frdhrapr, naq gung gur arkg ryrzrag bs rnpu frdhrapr vf jung lbh'er fryrpgvat, abg whfg na neovgenel ryrzrag bs gur tebhcvat).

Comment: @JeremyDover clarified (I hope?)